# How to find an invalid content-type being returned from nginx?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, twilio

We are using Twilio's API (using TwiML), and are serving ".wav" files to them via our standard Rails/Passenger/nginx stack. However, I'm running into an issue -- according to Twilio, our server is sending "application/octet-stream" for .wav files, instead of the required "audio/wav".

I've made sure both Rails (in the mime_types initializer) and nginx (in the mime.types file) have the appropriate mime type. Yet, roughly half the time, Twilio reports that it cannot retrieve the file due to an "application/octet-stream" mime type. The other half of the time, it works fine.

Has anyone experienced behavior like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have finally cleared this issue up... I modified our  verbs to use full URLs instead of a path, and I used HTTP protocol in those URLs.

```
# Old
<Play>/assets/path/to/file.wav</Play>

# New
<Play>http://server.com/assets/path/to/file.wav</Play>
```

I'm not sure whether it's the shift to HTTP, or the shift to URL, but my error rate immediately dropped from around 50% to 0%. I'll leave this open for other answers in case someone knows why this might be the case or they have another solution.

Comment: I am now having the same issue, but a switch to HTTP is not an option for us. Mime types are set correctly and we're using the full path, but the issue comes and goes as you described.

Comment: We solved it by just moving to mp3 instead of wav... kinda dumb. Also don't know why it happened.